# Check if DSC resource has been modified, if so, reboot

Tags: azure, dsc

I have a DSC script that runs in Azure Automation after a VM has been built by an ARM Template. It does a bunch of stuff, some of which I will show, including connecting to a domain. Prior to the domain there are parts of the script that will change server settings that don't actually 'come into effect' until the machine has been rebooted. I have the join domain part using these as `DependsOn` so when the machine does join the domain I know it will reboot and these settings fully applied.

However, I noticed the other day that these settings were changed later (days after deploying the server) and DSC advised that it was out of configuration because it hasn't restarted after applying the 'get back in configuration' part of the script.

I'm curious to know if there's a DSC resource that will check if ResourceX and ResourceY were modified/applied/changed, and if so, reboot the machine to have the change come into effect.

```
Registry DisableUAC
# Only fully applied after a reboot if changed
{
    Ensure = "Present"
    Key = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"
    ValueName = "EnableLUA"
    ValueData = "0"
    ValueType = "Dword"
}


Script LocationCulture
# Only fully applied after a reboot if changed
{
    GetScript =
    {
        Get-Culture | select -ExpandProperty Name
    }

    TestScript =
    {
        If (!((Get-Culture | select -ExpandProperty Name) -eq "en-GB")) {
            $false
        } else {
            $true
        }
    }

    SetScript =
    {
        Set-Culture en-GB
    }
}
```

These are two of four which require a reboot to apply. It would be good to have the machine reboot only once instead of after each re-alignment.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is such a resource, but if the resource explicitly sets the reboot flag on the VM you can use [xPendingReboot](https://github.com/PowerShell/xPendingReboot)

```
    xPendingReboot Reboot1
    { 
        Name = 'BeforeSoftwareInstall'
    }
    LocalConfigurationManager
    {
        RebootNodeIfNeeded = $True
    }
```

Comment: I've seen/read this, but sadly the UAC registry change (or even doing it via GUI) doesn't initiate any of the 3 locations which this module checks for a pending reboot. To check this I did a before/after snapshot of registry when enabling/disabling UAC and compared what was changed/created/deleted.

Comment: well, the only thing i can think of, is generate some files on the disk for each operation requiring a reboot and use a script resource that will check if the files are there, delete them and set the reboot flag. also, i believe there's the disable uac native resource.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the UAC resource